# How to create a horizontal list in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a horizontal list view in react-native. I know how to create a flat list and section list with just simple text , but I want the flat list to be horizontal

Comment: <FlatList
          data={data}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.space}
          horizontal={true}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center'}}>{item.num}</Text>
          }
        />

Answer (score 0):

Just add horizontal attribute to your FlatList

```
 <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={this.state.data}>
```

or

```
 <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        data={this.state.data}
```

Both above are same.

[image: sample]